# How to deploy SQL Server docker container at Google Cloud Run?

Tags: sql-server, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-bash) tutorial, I can run SQL Server in my local machine by using this command:

```
sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=<YourStrong@Passw0rd>" \
   -p 1433:1433 --name sql1 -h sql1 \
   -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

How can I run it on Google Cloud Run? What should I put in these config inside the Cloud Run?

- Container port
- Container command
- Container arguments

Comment: You cannot run a working container based upon Microsoft SQL Server in Cloud Run. 1) Cloud Run requires an HTTP Request/Response application similar to how a web server operates.  2) Cloud Run does not provide persistent storage. 3) Use Compute Engine to run these types of container images.

Comment: Im trying to host web api + sql server as docker container for learning, do you have any good recommendation for the hoster? Preferably pay as you use.

Comment: Details are required to recommend anything. As I said in my comment, use Compute Engine. Personally, I would run Docket on my desktop for learning.